# Environment Variables present in docker.compose.yml ignored when run by Visual Studio 2022

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a new project, added docker orchestation support to it.

Needed postgres, so added a postgres container definition into the docker-compose.yml. I set user and password.

Now, this works fine in command prompt. Running command "Docker-compose up", it sets up a postgres container with the wanted user credentials. I can see the user if I log into the container, and use the \du command. Also, have to log into the specific named container with the named user.

docker exec -it 7044a3219bb2  psql -U customUser -d snip

However, when run from Visual Studio, it runs some other command to set it up. It ends up with the same services, but initializes the same version of postgres as specified in the docker-compose file, but ignores all environment variables specified in the docker-compose file.

It does not contain the named user, instead connecting to it and checking via \du, I need to connect to the default postgres connection parameters, not my custom container or custom user.

docker exec -it 571a4f1c5ca5   psql -U postgres

To summarize, I can get the environmental variables properly set up in my own projects, but the from a postgres official image instantiated postgres container does not get the wanted environmental variables when started via Visual Studio.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  snip:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}snip
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: https://+:443;http://+:80
      DB_HOST: postgres  # Use the service name as the hostname
      DB_PORT: 5432      # PostgreSQL default port
      DB_NAME: snip
      DB_USER: customUser
      DB_PASSWORD: ReplaceMe-dum-dee-dum
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: modules/snip/snip.ADR.API/Dockerfile
      
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16-alpine3.18
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: snip
      POSTGRES_USER: customUser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ReplaceMe-dum-dee-dum
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```